# passing value from account.php to reg.blade.php?

Tags: javascript, php, global-variables, environment-variables, var

I want to know that how can access php variable assigned in one file from another file..

actually what i want to do is ..
H have account.php.there i have a value assigned to a variable like this.

```
enter code here
$_SESSION['google_data']['name']="some value";
```

now i have another file reg.blade.php in a different folder.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label>Student Name *</label>
   <input type="text" id="studentname" name="studentname" value=$AA placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control required"/>
    </div>
```

So in this file i want to have that previous name variable in the place of $AA

Both these are not in the same folder they are in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it looks like your using session variables as a way of saving your data between pages so once you've assigned

```
$_SESSION['google_data']['name']="some value";
```

As long as your opening the session on the next page using

```
session_start();
```

You'll want to open php using the normal syntax `<?php ?>` before the html and assign `$AA` with the value inside of `$_SESSION['google_data']['name']`.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$AA = $_SESSION['google_data']['name'];
?>
```

If you wondering how to access and see the data inside of `$_SESSION` then you can print it out using `print($_SESSION);`

reference http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp